# Python, Pandas ===> Create a New Column According to Other Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

*I have a dataframe like this :*

```
        nt
12062   Python Pandas: Create new column out of other columns where value is not null
12063   Python Pandas Create New Column with Groupby().Sum()
12064   
12065   Python - Pandas - create “first fail” column from other column data
12066   
12067   
12068   Creating new column in pandas based on value of other column
12070   Merge with pandas creating new columns?
```

*What I want to get is :*

Create a New Column (with column name is CreateC) that has row equals 1 if nt column has 'Create' word. Something like this :

```
        nt                                                                             CreateC
12062   Python Pandas: Create new column out of other columns where value is not null   1
12063   Python Pandas Create New Column with Groupby().Sum()                            1
12064                                                                           0
12065   Python - Pandas - create “first fail” column from other column data     1
12066                                                                           0
12067                                                                   0
12068   Creating new column in pandas based on value of other column    0
12070   Merge with pandas creating new columns?                         0
```

*what  i have done is :*

I create a new column base on index 
then find row include 'Create'
then find index number of these row

```
df['index1'] = df.index
dfCreate = df[df['dataframe'].str.contains("Create", na = False)]
dfCreateIndex = dfCreate.index.tolist()

def CreateCs (row):
    RowIndex1 = pd.to_numeric(row['index1'], errors='coerce')
    for i in dfCreateIndex:
        y = dfCreateIndex
        if RowIndex1 == y:
            return '1'
        else:
            return '0'
df['CreateC'] = df.apply(lambda row: CreateCs(row), axis=1)
```

but i only got :

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

***is there any easy way to do this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask and then convert `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `int` and then convert to `str` by another `astype` (if necessary):

```
df['CreateC'] = df['nt'].str.contains('Create', case=False).astype(int).astype(str)
print (df)
                                                      nt CreateC
12062  Python Pandas: Create new column out of other ...       1
12063  Python Pandas Create New Column with Groupby()...       1
12064                                                          0
12065  Python - Pandas - create “first fail” column f...       1
12066                                                          0
12067                                                          0
12068  Creating new column in pandas based on value o...       0
12070            Merge with pandas creating new columns?       0
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['CreateC'] = np.where(df['nt'].str.contains('Create', case=False), '1', '0')
print (df)
                                                      nt CreateC
12062  Python Pandas: Create new column out of other ...       1
12063  Python Pandas Create New Column with Groupby()...       1
12064                                                          0
12065  Python - Pandas - create “first fail” column f...       1
12066                                                          0
12067                                                          0
12068  Creating new column in pandas based on value o...       0
12070            Merge with pandas creating new columns?       0
```

Comment: thank you, 
second solution works for me, i slightly changed it  
`np.where(df['nt'].str.contains('Create', case=True, na = False, regex=True), '1', '0')`